Joomla is attempting to send emails to jmcms.site@google.com - why?
I recently changed to SMTP mail delivery method only to learn that Joomla fails to send certain empty messages to weird jmcms.site@google.com email address, which apparently doesn't exist.
I would assume it's some sort of a plugin, but I downloaded plugins folder and searched for that with no results. I can't find anything about this address in Google either. It looks kind of malicious. Well, if it worked, at least.
Or, as it turns out, it seems to be some default Joomla feature, since I also got some 4.4.5 version update emails today, also attempted to be sent to that address. I'm so confused.
How can I possibly debug the origin of the email and disable sending the email to prevent "delivery failure" message spam?

If it is a value that can be changed then it is more likely going to be saved in the data base and if it is a plugin as you suspect then I would start with #__extensions table  and look for the value in the field params.

It turned out to be some default Joomla email address since later today I got some emails that I got an upgrade to 4.4.5 available. No idea why previous emails were empty.
Also no clue why Joomla tries to send emails to that address at all. That address is not findable in source code on GitHub.

It turned out to be some random user with System Emails enabled in Users -> Manage.
No idea if an extension added it or someone who previously managed the site added the account. Neither why some of the system emails had no content.
Removing the account solved the problem though.
